# Converting geopackage to feature class (shapefile or geodatabase) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, convert, feature-class, geopackage

I work with ArcGIS Pro and got a geopackage (.gpkg) from a client. It seems that one cannot directly work with the geopackage data in ArcGIS, so I would like to convert it to a shapefile or feature class.

How can a geopackage be converted to a shapefile or a feature class **in** ArcGIS Pro?

I neither can use an online converter (file is too big) nor another GIS program.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most useful page from the documentation for this is the one titled [Work with SQLite databases and GeoPackage files in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/databases/work-with-sqlite-databases-in-arcgis-pro.htm):

> You can connect to an SQLite database or GeoPackage file in ArcGIS Pro
> to create maps and perform spatial analysis on your data. SQLite
> databases and OGC GeoPackage files support a single-user connection.
>
> ...
>
> Follow these steps to add a SQLite database or GeoPackage to your
> project:
>
> 1. Connect to a folder that contains the SQLite database or GeoPackage that you want to use.
> 2. In the **Catalog** pane, browse to the folder to which you connected in the previous step.
> 3. Right-click the SQLite database or GeoPackage and click **Add to Project**. The SQLite database or GeoPackage appears in the
>    **Catalog** pane under the **Databases** category.
> 4. Browse to the SQLite database or GeoPackage to start using its items.
>
> ...
>
> If you do not want to add the database or GeoPackage to the project,
> you can use the contents of the database directly from the folder
> connection.

In the Catalog you can Copy/Paste feature classes between a geopackage (`*.gpkg`) and a geodatabase or use:

- the Feature Class To Shapefile tool to get a shapefile feature class; or

[image]

- the Feature Class To Geodatabase tool to get a geodatabase feature class

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use to Copy Features function.

Just take the gpkg file as Input and save the output to a gdb.

[image: I just took an gpkg example an input and it worked straight away]